# Restrict certain characters from certain UITextField

Tags: ios, swift

I have a view controller with multi-UITextFields, and almost every text field must be restricted with certain characters. I'm using this code:

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")) == nil
}
```

It works well, but it works on all UITextFields, how can I make it work with a certain text field only?

Comment: This is a delegate function. You have to assign them manually, either via an IBOutlet or in code. Just create a new delegate

Comment: Well, just add a condition `if textField == myTextField { ... } else return true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the `textField` with the one you want to restrict input to

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == self.firsNameTxf {

        return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")) == nil }

    else {

         return true 
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a delegate method that is called each time you press a character on the keyboard, if it is working globally on all your text views means that you have a class that is delegate of all your text views.
To avoid that you can easily check inside the delegate who is calling it and apply this behavior just for one.

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard textField === noChartextField else {
    return true
}
    return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")) == nil
}
```

Note that here you can use the identity operator `===`, since you are just checking if `textField` and `noChartextField` are pointing to the same address of memory. I guess that `==` will work fine either since `UItextField` inherits from `NSObject` where the method `-isEqual`, if not overridden will check pointer equality as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please add texfield condition in delegate method like that:

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == firestTextField || textField == secondTextField {

        return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet(charactersIn: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")) == nil

        } 
      return true
 }
```